# Need persistent im memory cache with multi key lookups

Tags: caching, redis, hazelcast, distributed, gemfire

We are having a requirement , where we need to search for keys with multiple keys , and are looking for a multiple indexes .

For example: 
Trade data contains the below parameters:

- Date
- Stock
- Price
- Quantity
- Account

We will be storing each trade as a list with Stock as the key. This would give us the the ability to query , all the trades of a given stock. However , we would also have queries , like list of all the trades in an account. We would want to use this same cache to fetch this query instead of a new cache. The requirement is for an in memory cache(java) , as the latency requirement is very low. Also , we need a persistent cache , so that the cache is re-populated when the application is restarted.

Please let me know , if there is any good solution available , as the only way for persistent cache seems to be the distributed ones.

Comment: Did you check RediSearch.io?

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure queries are faster is to  create a TradeMeta Object with only the attributes you would like to query on ie

- Date Stock Price Quantity Account
  The TradeMeta Object can be stored in a Map with index on all the above keys . This ensure hazelcast maintains  relevant buckets for easy lookup internally.  Predicates can be set against this TradeMetaMap to fetch the keys . One you have the keys use getAsync to  fetch the full trade objects from tradeMap. 
  To persist the cache you would require the Hazelcast EnterpriseHD which  has HD storage and HotRestartStore